# How to set data variable outside Vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue.js for some data binding and data filtering. I have created a Vue object inside a .js file and I want to pass some data from outside the file.

This is my test object testFile.js

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:  "#results",
    data: {
        results: [],
    },
});
```

Now in my html i do this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        vm.results = [
        { name: 'Bron Smith', aliases: [], age: '', state: 'FL', locations: ['Miami','Orlando','Biscayne'], relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
    ];
};
 </script>
```

My Vue object gets the data but it doesn't show in the html.
Is there a way to pass this data and the data to actually show in the html?

Comment: Can u share your HTML code.

Comment: Try creating a computed property and using that property in the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    vm.$set(vm.results, [{
      name: "Bron Smith",
      aliases: [],
      age: "",
      state: "FL",
      locations: ["Miami", "Orlando", "Biscayne"],
      relatives: ["Dana Smith", "Diana Smith", "Test Smith"],
      report: "dsgsd"
    }]);
  };
</script>
```